# Recursive predicate to output difference of lists (without duplicated elements)

Tags: prolog

I have the below recursive predicate to check the set difference in lists and output these.

I have this working but also outputs duplicated values. 
Could anyone tell me how to fix this so that the output is without duplicated values. Thanks

```
setDiff([],Y,[]). 
setDiff([X|R],Y,Z) :- member(X,Y), setDiff(R,Y,Z). 
setDiff([X|R],Y,[X|Z]) :- \+(member(X,Y)), setDiff(R,Y,Z).
```

Expected output

```
?- setDiff([1,2,3,3,a], [b,d,2], X).

X = [a, 3, 1] ;
```

actual output

```
?- setDiff([1,2,3,3,a], [b,d,2], X).

X = [a, 3, 3, 1] ;
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to add a condition in rule 3, which unifies the third argument with `[X|Z]` if `X` isn't already in `Z`, and unifies it with `Z` if `X` is already in `Z`:

```
setDiff([],_,[]). 
setDiff([X|R],Y,Z) :- member(X,Y), setDiff(R,Y,Z). 
setDiff([X|R],Y,L) :- 
    \+ member(X,Y), 
    setDiff(R,Y,Z),
    (   member(X, Z) ->
        L = Z
    ;   L = [X|Z]
    ).
```

*Note: I replaced `Y` with `_` in the first rule, to avoid a "singleton variable" warning: there is indeed no need to name Y in that case because it is never used in the rule. This warning helps you detect probable errors where a named variable is only used once (which is never useful)*.

Comment: `X=b, setDiff([X],[a],[b]).` succeeds, yet its generalization `setDiff([X],[a],[b]).` fails. Consider `memberd_t/3`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it tail-recursive (so more efficient), you can use two parameters for the output list:

```
setDiff(Xs,Ys,Zs) :-
  setDiff(Xs,Ys,[],RevZs), reverse(RevZs,Zs).

setDiff([X|Xs],Ys,Zs0,Zs) :-
  ( ( member(X,Ys) ; member(X,Zs0) ) ->
    Zs1 = Zs0
  ; Zs1 = [X|Zs0] ),
  setDiff(Xs,Ys,Zs1,Zs).
setDiff([],_,Zs,Zs).
```

(This also avoids calling `member/2` twice with the same parameters.)